# Passing Data To Routes - Error: Cannot Match Any Routes

Tags: angular, typescript

I followed the instrucions of this page (https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/) to pass a id between modules to use it as a searching filter, but I get the cannot match any routes error and been stucked for a time because I'm new in angular so I really don't know what I could be doing wrong.

**Error Log**

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'municipality/%5B'./municipalityListDep',department.code%5D'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'municipality/%5B'./municipalityListDep',department.code%5D'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4295)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:4259)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:56)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

**municipality-listdep.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit }    from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute}         from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }           from 'rxjs';

import { MunicipalityService }  from '../municipality/municipality.service';
import { Municipality }         from '../municipality/municipality';
import { DepIsNumericalDirective } from '../directives/depisnumerical.directive';

@Component
({
    selector:       'municipality-listdep',
    templateUrl:    './municipality-listdep.component.html',
    styleUrls:      ['./municipality-listdep.component.css']
})

export class MunicipalityListDepComponent implements OnInit
{
    municipalities: Observable<Municipality[]>;
    code;
    sub;

    constructor(private municipalityService: MunicipalityService, private route: ActivatedRoute)
    {   }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.sub = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params =>
        {
            this.code = params.get('dep');
            let municipalities = this.municipalityService.getMunicipalitiesByDept(this.code);
        });
    }

    reloadData()
    {   this.municipalities = this.municipalityService.getMunicipalitiesByDept(this.code);  }

}
```

**municipality.component.html**

```
<h1>Municipios</h1>
<br />
<br />
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start">
    <div fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 10px)"><municipality-add></municipality-add></div>
    <div fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 10px)"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
    <div fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 10px)">
        <nav fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
            <a routerLink="municipalityList" class="button" role="button" routerLinkActive="active">Lista De Municipios</a>
            <a routerLink="['/municipalityListDep',department.code]" class="button" role="button" routerLinkActive="active">Lista De Municipios Por Departamento</a>
            <div fxLayout="row">
            <img id="arrow" src="assets/LArrow.png" style="width:5%;height:3%;">
            <select class="button" type="text" id="srdep" required [(ngModel)]="depcode" name="srdep">
                <option *ngFor="let department of departments | async" [value]="department.code">{{department.name}}</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**municipality.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit }    from '@angular/core';
import { Observable }           from 'rxjs';

import { Department }           from '../department/department';
import { DepartmentService }    from '../department/department.service';

@Component
({
    selector:       'municipality',
    templateUrl:    './municipality.component.html',
    styleUrls:      ['./municipality.component.css']
})

export class MunicipalityComponent implements OnInit
{
    departments: Observable<Department[]>;
    depc: string;

    constructor(private departmentService: DepartmentService)
    {   }

    ngOnInit()
    {   
        this.departments = this.departmentService.getDepartmentsList();
    }
}
```

**municipality-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }                         from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }             from '@angular/router';

import { MunicipalityComponent }            from './municipality.component';
import { MunicipalityListComponent }        from './municipality-list.component';
import { MunicipalityListDepComponent }     from './municipality-listdep.component';

const routes: Routes =
[
    {
        path: 'municipality',
        component: MunicipalityComponent,
        children:
        [
            {
                path:'',
                redirectTo:'municipalityList',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            { 
                path: 'municipalityList', 
                component: MunicipalityListComponent 
            },
            {
                path: 'municipalityListDep/:dep',
                component: MunicipalityListDepComponent
    }   ]   }
];

@NgModule
({
    imports:
    [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports:
    [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class MunicipalityRoutingModule
{   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer updated after I see the code in stackblitz.**

One of the problems is here:

**municipality.component.html**

```
<a routerLink="['/municipalityListDep',department.code]" class="button" role="button" routerLinkActive="active">Lista De Municipios Por Departamento</a>
```

At the moment you click the `<a routerLink="['/municipality/municipalityListDep',department.code]">` you are trying to navigate to `localhost:4200/municipalityListDep/:dep`

Instead of navigating to `localhost:4200/municipality/municipalityListDep/:dep` as you have configured in the **municipality-routing.module.ts**

You have to navigate relative to the url path: **`/municipality/municipalityListDep`**

In conclusion, first change:

**municipality.component.html**

```
<a routerLink="['../municipalityListDep',department.code]" class="button" role="button" routerLinkActive="active">Lista De Municipios Por Departamento</a>
```

Then, your second problem is the "department.code" that you use in the routerLink (I marked it with ('HERE->''<-HERE'):

```
<div fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 10px)">
    <nav fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <a routerLink="municipalityList" class="button" role="button" routerLinkActive="active">Lista De Municipios</a>
        <a routerLink="['../municipalityListDep','HERE->'department.code'<-HERE']" class="button" role="button" routerLinkActive="active">Lista De Municipios Por Departamento</a>
        <div fxLayout="row">
        <img id="arrow" src="assets/LArrow.png" style="width:5%;height:3%;">
        <select class="button" type="text" id="srdep" required [(ngModel)]="depcode" name="srdep">
            <option *ngFor="let department of departments | async" [value]="department.code">{{department.name}}</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I didn't see any variable or property in the municipality.component.ts, so I assume that you are using the "department" and the "department.code" of the *ngFor. In that case, the department is out of context for the `<a>`, because it's at a lower level than the `<a>`.
If you want to use the department.code of the `*ngFor` in the `<a>` I recommend you to move the `*ngFor` to other elements that contain the `<select>` and the `<a>` as children.

On the other hand, if you want to use the selected value in the `<select>` (as you did it right) you can save the value in a property (depcode) and the invoke it in the `<a>`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['../municipalityListDep',this.depcode]" class="button" role="button" routerLinkActive="active">Lista De Municipios Por Departamento</a>
```

Is this solving your problem?

Comment: Could you upload the code to (or this part of the code https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: @Seikikai thanks for uploading the code. Now I understand the problem. 
I will update my answer so I can help you.

Comment: @Seikikai, I have just finished updated my answer. Good Luck.

Comment: I changed the codes of:

**municipality.component.html**
```
 depcode: Department;
 depc: number;

 selectedDep()
 {
  this.depc = this.depcode.code;
 }
```

Comment: **municipality.components.ts**
`
   <a routerLink="['../municipalityListDep',this.depc]" class="button" role="button" routerLinkActive="active">Lista De Municipios Por Departamento</a>
   <div fxLayout="row">
   <img id="arrow" src="assets/LArrow.png" style="width:5%;height:3%;">
   <select class="button" type="text" id="srdep" required [(ngModel)]="depcode" name="srdep" (change)="selectedDep()">
    <option *ngFor="let department of departments | async" [value]="department.code">{{department.name}}</option>
   </select>
`

But the problem persist.

Comment: Ok. Could you update the code in stackblitz.com? Also, Could you upload the API or mock the data of the HTTP responses with JSON files or mock them in the code? Because yesterday when I used the code in stackblitz I couldn't try my changes because I don't have backend responses. Thanks.

Comment: I decided to simplify the code and merge the two modules to don´t keep bothering you with this and save time before the deadline. The program is working now as intended.

Anyways thanks for your help.